# Site Not Generating New Files

Tags: jekyll

My jekyll site is generating files fine on my computer but is not working at all on the server; I can edit the _site folder to make the changes happen, but it won't generate on the server. I am running `jekyll --server` with no errors. Any suggestions?

My _config.yml file is:

```
server: false
permalink: /:year/:title/
```

Comment: Do you mean: "When run in server mode, Jekyll is not generating new files"? Saying it "is not working at all on the server" makes it sound like you are also running Jekyll on another computer which is where the problem is. Also, how are you editing _site to make changes happen? Normally one changes the src folder. You can try specifying the src and destination folders with the --server switch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any plugins? Unless you have a server that can run Ruby, plugins won't run anywhere besides locally.  GitHub doesn't allow Ruby to be run for security reasons.

I'm surprised it's generating fine locally, since you should probably have `server:true`. More info on your server setup would be helpful if this doesn't solve your issues.